# How to refactoring database connection method with data from API - c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I try to change my database connection method with data from API and want to remove connection to database.

This is my database connection and I want to replace data from database with data from API.

```
public IEnumerable<AlertLevel> DataBaseConnection(int mapCode)
    {
        string ConnectionString = "server=192.168.1.1;uid=user;port=3333;pwd=password;database=dbName;";
        MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        var listAlert = new List<AlertLevel>();

        try
        {
            Conn.Open();

            //replace(2) with mapCode
            string query = "CALL Get_Alert_levels_Station(" + mapCode + ");";
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, Conn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    var currentData = new AlertLevel()
                    {

                        dateForecast = myReader.GetDateTime(0),
                        levelForecast = myReader.GetInt32(1)

                    };

                    listAlert.Add(currentData);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                myReader.Close();
                Conn.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Database Connection", "Not Connected ..." + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }

        return listAlert;
    }
```

This is my methods with API data:

```
string GenerateRequestUri(string endpoint)
    {
        string requestUri = endpoint;
        requestUri += $"?id=16";

        return requestUri;
    }

    string GenerateRequestUriStations(string endpoint)
    {
        string requestUri = endpoint;
        requestUri += $"stations";

        return requestUri;
    }


    public WaterBindingData GetData()
    {
        var reusult = _restServiceData.GetWaterDataForecast(GenerateRequestUriStations(Constants.EndPoint), GenerateRequestUri(Constants.EndPoint));

        
        foreach (var item in reusult.WaterData.Ardaforecast[0].Items)
        {
            item.DateTimeForecast.ToString();
            item.AlertLevelForecast.ToString();
        }

        return reusult;

    }
```

I want to put inside in `DataBaseConnection` method my API logic and want to put  `item.DateTimeForecast.ToString();` and `item.AlertLevelForecast.ToString();` in `AlertLevel` and also I don't know how to put dynamic variable in `GenerateRequestUri(string endpoint)`: `requestUri += $"?id=16";` 16 Have to be `mapCode`

Comment: why are you passing two different urls to `GetWaterDataForecast`?  If `GetData` is supposed to replace `DataBaseConnection` why do they have different return types?

Comment: The first url is for station names, the second is for data for each station.. (I don't need the url for stations..) I don't know why they have different return types.. Do you know how to import logic from GetData() inside in DatabaseConnection() ?

Comment: "I don't know why" - is this not the code you wrote?  Does `GetWaterDataForecast` actually work and return data?

Comment: Yes GetWaterDataForecast() and GetData() works and return data..\

Comment: The idea is that when you click on a pin from the map, I need to load data for MapCode.. so I don't want to load the data from the database, just want to load the data from item.DateTimeForecast and item.AlertLevelForecast.. but I don't know what can I do in this GetWaterDataForecast() method to work with API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to do something like this

```
string GenerateRequestUri(string endpoint, mapCode)
{
    string requestUri = endpoint;
    requestUri += $"?id={mapCode}";

    return requestUri;
}

public IEnumerable<AlertLevel> GetDataFromAPI(int mapCode)
{
   var listAlert = new List<AlertLevel>();

   var reusult = _restServiceData.GetWaterDataForecast(GenerateRequestUriStations(Constants.EndPoint), GenerateRequestUri(Constants.EndPoint), mapCode);

        
        foreach (var item in reusult.WaterData.Ardaforecast[0].Items)
        {
            var currentData = new AlertLevel()
                    {
                        dateForecast = item.DateTimeForecast.ToString(),
                        levelForecast = item.AlertLevelForecast.ToString()
                    };

                    listAlert.Add(currentData);
        }

        return listAlert;

    }
```